# The set of numbers whose decimal expansions contain only 4 and 7

Tags: analysis

Let $S$ be the set of numbers in $X=[0,1]$ that when expanded as a decimal form, the numbers are 4 or 7 only.

The following are the problems.

a), Is S countable ?

b), Is it dense in $X$ ?

c), Is it compact ?

d), Is it perfect ?

For a), I want to say that it is intuitively, but I have no idea how to prove this. I tried to come up with a bijection between $S$ and $\Bbb Z$ but I couldn't find one.

For b), my understanding of a set being "dense" means that all points in $X$ is either a limit point or a point in $S$. Am I right? Even if I were, I am not sure how to show this.

For c), my intuition tells me that it is because it is bounded. So if I could show that it is closed I will be done, I think.  But I am still iffy with the idea of limit points, and I am not sure what kind of limit points there are in $S$.

For d), Because I can't show that it's closed I am completely stuck.

I am teaching myself analysis, and I only know up to abstract algebra. Since I never took topology, please give me an explanation that helps without knowledge of advanced math.

Comment: Here's something to start you off.  The question, as it's posed, is purposefully tricky.  Imagine a bijection from your set $S$ to the set of all numbers in $X=[0,1]$ expressed in their binary expansion, i.e. they can only use $0$ or $1$ after the 'decimal' point.  Take $4\mapsto0$ and $7\mapsto 1$.  You'll agree that every number has a binary expansion.  Thus you may simply  considering the cardinality of $X$.

Comment: (a) No, (b) No, (c) Yes, (d) Yes. Now that you know the correct answers, all you have to supply is proofs. Of course this is impossible until you understand what the statements (a)-(d) mean. But you have a computer and there is a thing called wikipedia.

Comment: >Frank 
That was actually very helpful. Thank you very much.

>hot-queen
Thanks for your help. I don't use wikipedia as a math reference anymore since I found a mistake in several articles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your definition of $S$ is a little ambiguous, as stated. I am going to assume that the following is meant:

> $S$ is the set of all points $x\in[0,1]$ such that $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d_n}{10^n}$ for some sequence of $d_n$s with each $d_n\in\{4,7\}.$

We can then construct $S$ in a similar fashion to the famous [Cantor ternary set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_ternary_set#Construction_and_Formula_of_the_ternary_set). We define a sequence of sets $S_k$ recursively as follows:

> Let $S_0=[0,1]$.
>
> Given $S_k$, we define $S_{k+1}$ to be the points $x$ of $S_k$ such that $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d_n}{10^n}$ where each $d_n\in\{0,1,2,...,8,9\}$ and in particular $d_n\in\{4,7\}$ for all $1\le n\le k+1.$

For example:

$$S_1=\left[\frac4{10},\frac5{10}\right]\cup\left[\frac7{10},\frac8{10}\right]$$

$$S_2=\left[\frac{44}{100},\frac{45}{100}\right]\cup\left[\frac{47}{100},\frac{48}{100}\right]\cup\left[\frac{74}{100},\frac{75}{100}\right]\cup\left[\frac{77}{100},\frac{78}{100}\right],$$ and so on. More generally, you should verify that each $S_k$ will be the disjoint union of $2^k$ closed intervals, each of length $10^{-k}$. Hence, each $S_k$ has total length $2^k\cdot 10^{-k}=5^{-k}$.

As a union of finitely-many closed sets, each $S_k$ is closed. You should be able to see that $S$ is precisely the intersection of all the $S_k$s. Why can we then conclude that $S$ is closed?

$S$ is certainly not dense in $[0,1]$, since it is a closed proper subset of $[0,1]$. In fact, it is [nowhere dense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set) there, since it is closed, and contains no open set but the empty set. Indeed, if $U$ is a non-empty open set, then it contains an open interval $I$ of positive length, but we can make the total length of the $S_k$ as small as we like by taking $k$ large enough, so $I$ isn't contained in all the $S_k$, whence $I$ can't be contained in $S$, and so $U$ can't be contained in $S$, either.

To see that $S$ is in fact *uncountable*, let $f:\{4,7\}\to\{0,1\}$ be given by $f(4)=0,f(7)=1$, and define a function $g$ on $S$ by $$g\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d_n}{10^n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(d_n)}{2^n}.$$ I leave it to you to show that $g$ maps $S$ bijectively to $[0,1]$--you must show that $g$ is one-to-one, and maps $S$ *into and onto* $[0,1]$--so is uncountable. Some basic knowledge of series will come in handy, here.

To show that $S$ is perfect, you need to show that all points of $S$ are accumulation points. Take any point $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d_n}{10^n}$ in $S$, and let $r>0$. There exists $N$ large enough so that $\frac3{10^N}<r$. (Why?) Let $b_n=d_n$ for all integers $n\ge1$ with $n\ne N$, and let $b_N\in\{4,7\}$ with $b_N\ne d_N$. Putting $$y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b_n}{10^n},$$ it should then be clear that $y\in S,$ $y\ne x$, and $|y-x|<r$. Since $r>0$ was arbitrary, then $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$. Since $x\in S$ was arbitrary, all points of $S$ are accumulation points.

---

Once you've worked through the details of the above, test your understanding by adapting the arguments to show that the following set is uncountable, compact, perfect, and nowhere dense:

> Let $T$ be the set of all points $x$ in $[0,1]$ such that $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{q_n}{4^n}$ for some sequence of $q_n$s with each $q_n\in\{1,3\}$.

Comment: I truly appreciate the great detail and effort you put in for me. It made perfect sense and I think I understand it a bit more. I will try to work on the problem you gave me to see if I really got it down.

Comment: Sir, just as in case of binary expansion or in case ternary expansion we takes $d_n$ to be $0$ or $1$ or $0$, $1$, $2$. Why did you here consider $d_n\in \{0,1,2,...,9\}$ ? Please reply

Comment: @Akash: Because it is a decimal expansion. In general, for any $k$-ary expansion, each $d_n$ will be an integer from $0$ to $k-1,$ inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:  For b, can you get close to $0.2?$

For c, you are correct that it is bounded, so you need to investigate closed.  Let $y \in [0,1]$, but $y \not \in S$.  Then there is some digit of $y$ that is not $4$ or $7$....

For d, you need to show that any point of $S$ is a limit of a sequence of other elements of $S$.  Let $x \in S$.  Can you find a list of other elements in $S$ that get closer and closer to $x$?  For starters, can you describe another point within $\pm 0.1$ of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

S is not countable because any countable subset of S must be a proper subset. To see this, suppose that A is contained in S and A is countable,  then its elements can be displayed  in some sequence x_1,x_2,...,x_n,.... We shall construct a number x of S that not belongs to A.

If x_n have 4 at the nth decimal position, x have 7 at the nth position. And vice versa.

So x differs from any element of A,hence x does not belongs to A. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of people saying that the set is perfect, however, I could be wrong, but I would agree that the interpretation above is valid, but not the only one and I offer a different interpretation because the question is ambiguous, as the top answer states.  If we are accepting that any digit before the decimal point is zero, then I would argue that it both the set of arbitrary digit length, and the set of infinite digit length are included in this, hence the set given by $S$ is defined such that it is the infinite union of sets $S_n$ such that $S_n$ has $n$ digits after the decimal of that are either $4$ or $7$ all unioned with the set of infinite digit strings, which we can denote by $S_a$. Hence because it is an infinite union it does contain infinite digit strings, and finite digit strings.  So any infinite digit string is a limit point, but any finite digit string is not a limit point, so $S$ is not perfect.  Maybe I am just interpreting the question wrong, but if I am I don’t see why this isn’t a valid interpretation of the question, as it could be potentially ambiguous.  This question is from `Baby Rudin Chapter 2 Exercise 17`.  So if my interpretation is against the typical convention let me know, but otherwise I believe it is an accurate representation and hence the set is not perfect with my reasoning.